# Filenet query number conversion in order by

Tags: data-conversion, filenet-content-engine, filenet-ce-sql

I have this Filenet query:

```
SELECT 
    [This], [Ente], [IDAtto], [Numero], [Tipologia], [DataEmissione] 
FROM   
    [AttoNormativo] 
WHERE 
    ([DataEmissione] > 20160405T215959Z AND [DataEmissione] < 20160408T220001Z) 
ORDER BY 
    [DataEmissione] desc, [Tipologia], [Numero], [Ente]
OPTIONS (TIMELIMIT 180)
```

The problem is that `[Numero]` property is string type, so it does not order properly. There is some cast function that I can use to convert it numeric?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation, properties of type `Boolean`, `DateTime`, `Float64`, `ID`, `Integer32`, and `Object` may appear in an `ORDER BY` clause, along with `short String` properties. Neither `Binary` nor `long String` properties may be used to order a query.

You can define a custom string property to store in either a short or long database column by setting the `UsesLongColumn` property when the property is created.

Now - if you are worried about the `null` values, then you may consider using the `COALESCE` function.

```
<orderby> ::= [ COALESCE '(' <property_spec>, <literal> ')' || <property_spec> ] [ ASC | DESC ]
```

You can find more about Relational Queries - [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. According to [the docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/query_sql_syntax_rel_queries.htm?cp=SSNW2F_5.2.0) the orderby is a property_spec followed optionally by ASC or DESC.

```
<orderby> ::= <property_spec> [ ASC | DESC ]
```

The only function allowed in the ORDER BY is COALESCE() which can be used to provide a default sorting value when the data is null.